# How to find UIATableView child elements with UIAutomation predicate?

Tags: java, ios, selenium, xpath

I'm using Appium (Selenium based) to write UI tests for my iOS app.

My problem is to find all the cells and groups of a UITableView, in the order they appear.

For example, this structure represents a table with the first group open:
UIATableGroup
--UIATableCell
--UIATableCell
--UIATableCell
--UIATableCell
UIATableGroup
UIATableGroup
UIATableGroup
UIATableGroup

I am able to get a list in the above order by using xpath:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/*"))
```

The problem is that xpath is extremely slow, so I've been refactoring the code using iOS UIAutomation calls.

I can get all groups with this predicate:

```
driver.findElements(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0].groups()[0]"))
```

and all cells with this:

```
driver.findElements(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0].cells()[0]"))
```

But the problem is that I want to have both with the order preserved as above.

Shot in the dark guess:

```
driver.findElements(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0].withPredicate(\"ALL valid == true\")"));
```

The idea was to use the fact that both groups and cells have a 'valid' field but this just crashes the tests.

How can I get the UIAutomation / predicate equivalent of what I did with xpath?

Comment: Quick ques: have you tried ".tableViews()[0]"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some guessing I was able to come up with this:

```
driver.findElements(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0].elements()"))
```

It's still pretty slow but it works.